# Java 7u55 affecting existing applets

Tags: java, applet

Has anyone noticed any problems running existing applets with Java 7u55 that ran ok on older versions of Java? The applet doesn't even appear to get loaded, so I get no exeptions to try and diagnose the issue.

Comment: Try to enable the console in the Java Settings of the client.

Comment: ... and once you have opened it set the logging level to fine to see the logs emitted by the java plugin.

Comment: Hi, i have tried that too - the console doesn't open. im guessing because the applet is being loaded

Comment: Same issue here. In my case, the applet is correctly signed with a NO-autosigned cert and property Caller-Allowable-Codebase has a standalone "*". The issue didn't exist before 7u55.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 update 51 introduced a lot of new security restrictions.
Changes can be found here: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml

You probably need to adapt you're existing code base to be compatible with the new requirements.

Comment: Hi Mathias, it works fine with 7u51 but stopped working with 7u55

Comment: They've added a new restriction in the update 55:

Using "*" in Caller-Allowable-Codebase Attribute
If a stand-alone asterisk (*) is specified as the value for the Caller-Allowable-Codebase attribute, then calls from JavaScript code to RIA will show a security warning, and users have the choice to allow the call or block the call.

Comment: Hi Mathias, i am seeing this pop-up on some PCs and an then accept and continue using the program but on others the applet doesn't load at all. i have hecked the java settings and they are identical. any more ideas?

Comment: We had a similar issue with update 51, but all our clients failed to launch the application. Not just some of them... After we updated the manifest file and made sure that every jar in the codebase was properly signed, the problem was resolved.